# org.mongodb.driver.cluster Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server

Tags: java, docker

tengo una aplicación hecha en java con spring boot, estoy desplegando con docker en upcloud, en mi local todo funciona, pero en el servidor me sale este error:

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:204) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:199) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:159) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:331) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:630) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:299) ~[na:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:82) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:68) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
... 4 common frames omitted

saben que puedo hacer?

Comment: Buenas, ¿has comprobado que el servidor Mongo que usas en local tiene la misma versión que el remoto? Quizás es un problema de incompatibilidad de drivers y tengas que modificar el que usas.

Comment: Es un servidor en upcloud nuevo, estoy despegando con docker,  la base de datos es remota, no tengo la base de datos local, en mi maquina funciona pero en el servidor no, si alguien me puede ayudar le puedo pagar, es que estoy aprendiendo a montar mi propio servidor